# Can I compare two floats without loading them on the x87 stack?

Tags: assembly, x86, floating-point

Sorry for the elementary question.

In assembly is it acceptable to compare two floating points stored at different (fixed) memory locations without loading them into the stack? Do I need to use anything besides CMP and JLE?

E.g. Memory address [A] currently equals 95, memory address [B] equals [90]. I want to do a jump if [A] is less than or equal to 90. Is the following sufficient?

```
CMP DWORD PTR [A], CMP DWORD PTR [B]
JLE [Another address]
```

Comment: No that is not valid, and no, that is not even a floating point comparison.

Comment: For context, can you say what level of CPU/FPU you are programming for?  Are you retrocomputing for a classic 8087, 80287, Pentium?  Or do you have a computer from the last 20 years that has SSE?  The standard way to do a floating point compare varies among these.  (But none of them can compare two memory operands. And `cmp` does integer comparisons, which are not correct for floating point, so a different instruction is needed.)

Comment: Nate, it's an x87 executable from 1998

Answer (score 2):

If both floats are positive, and you don't care about issues like NAN:

```
        mov     eax,[a]
        cmp     eax,[b]
        jbe     ...
```

If either float can be negative, but not negative zero (080000000h):

```
        mov     eax,[a]
        cmp     eax,[b]
        mov     ecx,eax
        sar     ecx,31
        or      ecx,080000000h
        xor     eax,ecx
        mov     ecx,ebx
        sar     ecx,31
        or      ecx,080000000h
        xor     ebx,ecx
        cmp     eax,ebx
        jbe     ...
```

Negative 0 will end up 07fffffffh, less than positive 0 which ends up 080000000h. If this is an issue, the code would need to be modified.

Comment: Thank you! Both floats are positive. The actual floats are between 1 and 0 so could be considered normalised? Just a quick question though. Does MOV EAX/EBX overwrite the EAX/EBX value, or is it the equivalent of doing a PUSH? If the original EAX or EBX value is needed before and after this little loop should I do a push and pop?

Comment: @user1708538 "normalized" means a non-zero exponent field.  Magnitude >= `FLT_MIN`.  Subnormal aka denormal floats have an exponent encoded as zero, implying a leading `0` bit in the mantissa.  `FLT_MIN > |x| >= FLT_TRUE_MIN`.  Knowing that values are between 1 and 0 doesn't rule out subnormals.

Comment: @user1708538:    **However, you don't actually need your floats to be normalized for integer comparison to work, just not NaN.**  Doing an integer Increment on the bit-pattern monotonically increases the magnitude of the value represented by the float up from zero to Infinity; this is how `nextafterf(x, Infinity)` works.

Comment: @user1708538: Yes, of course this overwrites whichever registers you use.  Pick registers that aren't in use, save/restore them somewhere, or use x87 or SSE registers with `fcomi` (P6) or [`ucomiss` (SSE1)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ucomiss) respectively if the integer registers are all in use.

Comment: Peter, whenever I have asked a question here, you have always been a great help. Thank you. This memory address will always be *a* number of some kind, but what if it is 00000000? In that case, I presume "0" will be moved to EAX? Then I can do a test eax, eax ?

Comment: @x87-Learner: yes, the bit-pattern for 0.0 is `0x00000000`.  https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format .  And yes, comparing a single number against zero is even easier with integer compares, that always Just Works except for NaN, so `cmp dword [a], 0` (or load and `test eax,eax`) / `jle less_or_equal_to_zero`.  Negative zero gets treated as negative, not zero, but that's ok with jle or jg, but not je or jl (or jge).

Comment: Peter, I just tried it with cmp dword [a], 0 and it is all working exactly as intended. Many, many thanks!

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Answer should be fixed now.

Comment: Related: [Compare floating point numbers as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33678827) for another mapping from FP bit-pattern to comparable-integer.