# benefit to convert float values to bitwise integer before comparing?

Tags: c#, floating-point, grpc, grpc-c#

When we compare two objects of the same class in c# which is generated from a proto file, we can use `Equals()` since grpc protobuf overwrites `Equals()` for us to compare each fields.

However, for float and double fields,
there's ProtobufEqualityComparers like this:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Provides a central place to implement equality comparisons, primarily for bitwise float/double equality.
  /// </summary>
  public static class ProtobufEqualityComparers
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an equality comparer for <typeparamref name="T" /> suitable for Protobuf equality comparisons.
    /// This is usually just the default equality comparer for the type, but floating point numbers are compared
    /// bitwise.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of equality comparer to return.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The equality comparer.</returns>
    public static EqualityComparer<T> GetEqualityComparer<T>()
    {
      if (typeof (T) == typeof (double))
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) ProtobufEqualityComparers.BitwiseDoubleEqualityComparer;
      if (typeof (T) == typeof (float))
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) ProtobufEqualityComparers.BitwiseSingleEqualityComparer;
      if (typeof (T) == typeof (double?))
        return (EqualityComparer<T>) ProtobufEqualityComparers.BitwiseNullableDoubleEqualityComparer;
      return !(typeof (T) == typeof (float?)) ? EqualityComparer<T>.Default : (EqualityComparer<T>) ProtobufEqualityComparers.BitwiseNullableSingleEqualityComparer;
    }
```

Specifically, there's a BitwiseDoubleEqualityComparer used for double values and BitwiseSingleEqualityComparer for float values.

Why do we need them?

I believe BitwiseDoubleEqualityComparer and BitwiseSingleEqualityComparer cannot solve precision issues when comparing floating numbers.

Comment: It's not about precision issues, floating-points work differently on values which aren't finite. (also negative zero)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46995665/936310

Comment: Bitwise comparisons should not be used for numerical comparisons of floating-point numbers. They can be useful when managing floating-point numbers as objects, such as when storing them in hash tables or sorted containers. In those cases, you would usually want more than just an equality comparison; you would want the bits as an integer (for hashing) or would want ordered comparisons.

Comment: So why people in Google implement the proto comparator like this? For NaN, infinity and positive/negative zero only?

Comment: @ZZ: I suspect that it is because the protobuf folks don't compare about the semantics of floating point numbers and floating point equality, only the actual are these two things exactly the same nature of equality. If one packet contains a negative zero number while another has a positive zero number (and with everything else the same), then the two packets are different, even though the represent the same thing semantically